# How I can put " within an HTML attribute value

Tags: html, escaping, html-entities, quotations

I wish to have the following:

```
<span title="This is a "good" title.">Catch me in the rice.</span>
```

It is obvious that this is not rendered well by the browsers. Please provide me with information of what escape sequence or encoding like " I must use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either replace the quotation mark with its corresponding HTML entity — e.g. `&quot;` or `&#34;`) — like this:

```
<span title="This is a &quot;good&quot; title.">Catch me in the rice.</span>
<span title="This is a &#34;good&#34; title.">Catch me in the rice.</span>
```

Alternatively you can use single quotes in your HTML in cases where you need double quotes in attribute values:

```
<span title='This is a "good" title.'>Catch me in the rice.</span>
```

Comment: Single quotes will not work when the text he needs has a single quote in it... always use the entity.

Comment: @gms8994 Well of course stuff like `<foo bar='bar'baz'>` won’t work — I’m pretty sure the OP knows that, seeing as he asked a similar question (`<foo bar="bar"baz">`).

Answer (score 5):

Use `&quot;` instead.

Comment: That was fast. let me try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span title="This is a &quot;good&quot; title.">Catch me in the rise.</span>
```